# UTF-8 string to ordinal value: Java equivalent for Python output

Tags: java, python, utf-8, byte, utf

I have the feeling this is most likely a duplicate, but I'm unable to find it.

NOTE: My Python knowledge is very limited, so I'm not 100% sure how strings, bytes, and encodings are done in Python. My knowledge about encodings in general is also not too great..

Let's say we have the string `"Aä$$€h"`. It contains three different ordinary ASCII characters (`A$h`), and two non-ASCII characters (`ä€`). In Python we have the following code:

```python
# coding: utf-8
input = u'Aä$$€h'
print [ord(c) for c in input.encode('utf-8')]
# Grouped per character:
print [[ord(x) for x in c.encode('utf-8')] for c in input_code]
```

Which will output:

```python
[65, 195, 164, 36, 36, 226, 130, 172, 104]
[[65], [195, 164], [36], [36], [226, 130, 172], [104]]
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/X1khOT8lMy/dSqG0JE3Xgiszr6C0JB4olmpbqu54eImKyqOmNRnqXAVFmXklCtH5RSkayZoKaflFCskKmXkKCOV6qXkgSkMdbI66ZixMC1hPBURPBUhPMoZSbObF/v8PAA)

Now I'm looking for a Java equivalent giving this same integer-array. I know all Strings in Java are by default encoded with UTF-16, and only byte-arrays can have an actual encoding. I thought the following code would give the result I expected:

```java
String input = "Aä$$€h";
byte[] byteArray = input.getBytes(java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(byteArray));
```

But unfortunately it gives the following result instead:

```java
[65, -61, -92, 36, 36, -30, -126, -84, 104]
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##PU4xDoJAEOx5xYZQQOHVJsYCTeys0MoYs3AXOISD3C0kxND4Fkt/4U/8CB5cYjXZmdmZKbHHVcnv05RVaAwcUaqHB9B2aSUzMIRkoW8kh9pKYUJaqvxyBYxmG4AjQKq2I9iCH39eQfB9vgt/s@jpQMLaZ4i1xsF6Fi/LBe0sacLSTmBKNiwrUBtBLCFUHDXfu9uw8@lwW0cuLxkMiZo1NqG1zVQpF9CRrNjSYBg1blX4b42W79Ebp@kH)

I'm not sure where these negative values are coming from..

So my question is mostly this:

Given a String in Java containing non-ASCII characters (i.e. `"Aä$$€h"`), output its ordinal UTF-8 integers similar as the Python `ord`-function does on an UTF-8 encoded byte. The first part of this question, in that we already have a Java String, is a precondition for this question.

Comment: "all Strings in Java are _by default_ encoded with UTF-16": From the API perspective (esp. `.length`), there is no other option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java `byte` is signed, that is where the negative numbers are coming from. Bit-wise the numbers have the same value in both languages, the way they are being represented is just different. You can get the same representation as in python by using [`Byte.toUnsignedInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Byte.html#toUnsignedInt(byte)):

```
String input = "Aä$$€h";
byte[] byteArray = input.getBytes(java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
int[] ints = new int[byteArray.length];
for(int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
    ints[i] = Byte.toUnsignedInt(byteArray[i]);
}
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(ints));
```

Which prints:

```
[65, 195, 164, 36, 36, 226, 130, 172, 104]
```

Comment: Ah, so that was the difference here. Thanks! I will accept your answer in a few minutes when I can.